# How to compare growth rates estimated from GLMM?

Tags: r, mixed-model, interaction, multiple-comparisons, growth-model

I've counted aphid populations under 5 different treatments for about 10 weeks. There were 4 replicates of every treatment. I'm interested in comparing the first 4-5 weeks, where the populations increase, between the treatments to see which treatment had the highest growth rate.

I've fitted a GLMM to the data, with log(aphids+1) as response variable (aphids as mean no. aphids/leaf), treatment as fixed effect, time (in days) as covariate and replicate as random effect.

The interaction between treatment and time was significant, meaning there are different intercepts and slopes for every treatment. To visualize the model estimates, I calculated the number of aphids on each day for every treatment by filling in the formula:

```
#aphids = exp( (intercept + interceptTreatment) + (slope + slopeTreatment)*time )
```

And plotted these results, which looks like this:
[image]

But I'm confused on how to compare the actual growth rates. These are the slopes, thus the interactions? multcomp::glht() only compares the factor levels (treatments) and gives a warning that it found a covariate interaction.

Also: I log transformed the data first and needed to exp() to get the above graph. But then what is the growth rate estimate? The one that is still log transformed or the number after I do exp()? The first one is the slope of a straight line, but these populations grow exponentially which is clear on the plot for treatment E.

Code:

```
# packages
library(lme4)
library(multcomp)
library(ggplot2)

# data
aphLeaf <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0,0,0,0.033,0.067,0,
       0.333,0,0,0,0.067,0.4,0,0.033,0.2,0.233,0.433,0,0.033,2.233,0,0.567,0.033,0.6,0,
       0.433,0,0.167,2.6,1.1,0,4.4,0,0.633,12.867,6.4,6.467,0,0.1,2.267,0.033,0.867,0.033,
       1,0,0.267,0.867,0.067,0.9,0.3,0.233,1.867,0.133,6.967,21.233,10.2,11.5)
time <- rep(c(0,14,22,27), each=20)
treatment <- rep(rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),each=4),4)
replicate <- rep(c("A1","A2","A3","A4","B1","B2","B3","B4","C1","C2","C3","C4",
            "D1","D2","D3","D4","E1","E2","E3","E4"),4)
data <- data.frame(aphLeaf, time, treatment, replicate)

# GLMM
model <- lmer(log(aphLeaf+1) ~ treatment * time + (1+time|replicate), data)
drop1(model, test="Chisq") #interaction effect significant
summary(model)
```